# Does Android UI development lend itself well to a particiular design pattern?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvp

Does the Android platform lend itself well to a particular style of UI programming like MVC or MVP?  Most of my UI experience is with spaghetti code on a very old embedded device or in GWT with MVP so I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if the Android lends itself well to a *specific* design pattern when it comes to UI development per se, you can certainly use a particular pattern if it helps.

When in doubt you can check out the standard [**User Interface Guidelines**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) and see what the guidelines are for particular interactions.

Answer (score 14):

The MVC Pattern is more or less pre build into android.

You have three layers consisting of:

- **The Model** Your data classes, Content providers etc. wrapping all your data.
- **The Controllers** Treat all your activities as controller classes. Don't do anything in them that looks like business logic or data persitance. Just react to events from the model or the user and forward them to the correct layer.
- **The View** Often the Activities are called the view because there it is the java code that is closest to the views. But in my opinion the view layer in Android is mostly defined in xml. You define your buttons, images, state changes etc in xml and then connect it with your application through your Activities.

There are some simple rules to follow to have a basic separation of this layers.

- Define as much of your UI in xml only
  instantiate Views yourself if there
  is no other way to achieve something,
  don't change the graphical state of
  views from code, for example don't
  change the background of a button if
  the button is deactivated, or the
  color of a font if a button was
  clicked, do all this through stateful
  drawables, and selectors in xml.
- Don't do any data saving or logic in
  your activity classes. Call to extra
  model classes for this purpose. This
  will make your activities clean and
  short
- If you want to change your data think
  about    going through a full
  controller    changes model -> model
  informs    controller about changes
  ->    controller changes UI cycle instead    of having the controller
  change the    model and the UI
  directly because    other observers
  of the modes may not    be notified.